# Open keyboard on EditText focused

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C91WV.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVdOt.png)

I have a `RecyclerView` with some shit in it and a button that hides it all and shows an `EditText`. The problem is that the keyboard isn't opening. I tried like everything but it won't work.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/klasseEditItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

This is how the EditText looks like.

```
 holder.editKlasse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this hides the other items that i dont need. 
            holder.klasse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.deleteKlasse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.editKlasse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.editKlasseText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.fertigKlasse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            holder.editKlasseText.setText(KlassenListe.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
            holder.editKlasseText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (holder.editKlasseText.hasFocus()) {
                       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                       imm.showSoftInput(holder.editKlasseText,0);
                    }
                }
            });
            //this is the confirmation button to save the editText text and hide it again
            holder.fertigKlasse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.klasse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.deleteKlasse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.editKlasse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.editKlasseText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.fertigKlasse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

here, try this

```
 public static void showKeyboard(Context context) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: worked with an OnClick listener on the EditText but now the keyboard is behind the AlertDialog in which the editText is. You have an Idea how to fix that

Comment: I am getting a hard time what you trying to achieve, your quote "I have a RecyclerView with some shit in it and a button that hides it all and shows an EditText", hides mean, you want recyclerview visibility gone on clicking a button and shows etx ! right

Comment: I have an AlertDialog in which i display some Data in textViews. Each Item has an Edit button and when its pressed the button and the text view get invisible and an edittext is set visible to edit the text in the textview.

Comment: post some screenshot

Comment: Look in the main question. I have added two

Comment: I added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to manifest but it didnt changed anything